# how to get mood list of a user from spotify?

Tags: ios, spotify

I am developing an App which is related to spotify,in which there is tab for mood list on tapping that tab i want to display mood list from a spotify user account, I have used libspotify sdk but there is no feasibility for mood. if anyone done this please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but could you please elaborate a little bit on what you mean by mood list? If this is an iOS application, I'd recommend that you have a look at the [iOS SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/).

Comment: hi michaelt , mood list means when you login spotify account then under the browse button there is a "Genres and Moods" tab when you tap    this tab then mood button display, if you click mood button then mood list shows

Comment: Ok. So if I understand you correctly, you want to display the same playlists that appear in Browse's mood view?

Comment: Yes michaelt, if you have any idea then please tell me

Comment: Sure. We do have some of Browse's features exposed, as documented at https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/browse-endpoints/. We're working on exposing more data from Browse, so please follow the progress on the Developer site or our Twitter account @SpotifyPlatform.